# iPhone functionality with images, click thumbnail and display large image

Tags: html, image, jquery-mobile

Hi there I am developing a mobile site (NOT AN APP) for an iPhone.

This is a really noob question though I have searched and not really found what I am looking for, as I am not sure which exact search terms to use.

On an iPhone when you click an image it shows that image larger on the screen so you can zoom in/out.

I am using generated thumbnails that are a lot smaller than the original image, how do I load in a full resoloution image when a thumbnail is clicked?

again sorry for the noob question, if someone can point me in the right direction, part of the problem is that I have NO experience of mobile websites or iphone functionality, I will keep playing with jquery mobile and see where I get with that.

Comment: You just want to show the image normally with `<a href="foo.jpg">`?

Comment: yes but when its clicked i want to show the image full-screen but an alternate high rs image, not the thumbnail that was clicked.

Comment: What you could do, is create a new page dynamically and add an image to it. i'll work on an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the thumbnail, you may redirect the user to an another HTML page where is include the image with a max-width and max-height in %.

In mobile, it's better to have a design in % to adapt the design at all mobiles screen.

```
<img src="myImage.jpg" alt="myImage" id="myImg" />
```

And in CSS

```
#myImg{
max-height:100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

You have others solutions, by using jQuery plugins too : http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Raphael, that points me in the right direction, so when an image is clicked, its like a hyperlink to the image, i in fact was going to start looking at jQuery mobile, i use standard jQuery a lot, so should be nice to work with.
In your code you have myImage.jpg as the source, i would have myImageThumb.jpg as the souve (my thumbnail image) then when the image is clicked i want to go to the full size image myImageFull.jpg not the low res thumbnail image...

Comment: I think, you have to do that :

first :
`<a href="myImg.html"><img src="myImageThumb.jpg"></a>`

You will go to myImg.html :
`<img src="myImage.jpg" alt="myImage" id="myImg" style="max-height:100%; max-width: 100%;" />`

it would be good like this i think.